# How do I simple remove duplicates in my vector?

Tags: visual-c++

I am new to coding and struggling with a section in my code. I am at the part where i want to remove duplicate int values from my vector.

my duplicated vector contains: 1 1 2 1 4

my goal is to get a deduplicated vector: 1, 2, 4.

This is what I have so far, It also needs to be a rather simple solution. No pointers and fancy stuff as I still need to study those in the future.

```
for(int i = 0; i < duplicatedVector.size(); i++) {
        int temp = duplicatedVector.at(i);
        int counter = 0;
        if(temp == duplicatedVector.at(i)) {
            counter++;
            if(counter > 1) {
                deduplicatedVector.push_back(temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Could anyone tell me what I do wrong ? I genuinly am trying to iterate through the vector and delete duplicated int, in the given order.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: @user3091996 sadly, it happens quite often. Often, having got an answer they want to hide the question. Perhaps it is course work and they do not want their teacher to see the help they received. Perhaps they do not want to be embarrassed by letting their work colleagues know they asked for help. Occasionally you see people saying that the code/question has proprietary information and they did not have permission to make it public. I expect there are several other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is not well-enough thought out.

Break it up:

1. for each element of the original vector:
2. is it in the result vector?
   yes: do nothing
   no: add it to the result vector

You have your (1) loop, but the (2) part is confused. The result vector is not the same as the original vector, and is not to be indexed the same.

To determine whether an element is in a vector, you need a loop. Loop through your result vector to see if the element is in it. If you find it, it is, so break the inner loop. If you do not, you don't.

You can tell whether or not you found a duplicate by the final value of your inner loop index (the index into the result vector). If it equals `result.size()` then no duplicate was found.

Clearer variable naming might help as well. You are calling your original/source vector `duplicatedVector`, and your result vector `deduplicatedVector`. Even `hasDuplicates` and `noDuplicates` would be easier to mentally parse.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a set since it eliminates duplicates:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    vector<int> vec = vector<int>();
    vector<int> dedupl = vector<int>();
    vec.push_back(2);
    vec.push_back(4);
    vec.push_back(2);
    vec.push_back(7);
    vec.push_back(34);
    vec.push_back(34);
    set<int> mySet = set<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        mySet.insert(vec[i]);
    }

    for (int elem : mySet) {
        dedupl.push_back(elem);
    }

    for (int elem : dedupl) {
        cout << elem << " ";
    }

}
```

Comment: You should note that `std::set` does not preserve ordering, should that matter. In terms of available C++ facilities, there is also `std::unique()` in `<algorithm>`, which _does_ preserve ordering.